# Not able to build the project with SwiftyJSON on iOS 12

Tags: ios, swift, swifty-json, ios12

#### What did you do?

1. Using Carthage
2. This is my command in Cartfile. 
   github "SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON" ~> 4.0
3. Building the project on iOS 12 simulator

#### What did you expect to happen?

Project should build successfully.

#### What actually happened instead?

Project not built successfully. XCode showing the below error.

`ld: /Users/xxxxxx/Desktop/Test12/Carthage/Build/iOS/SwiftyJSON.framework/SwiftyJSON compiled with older version of Swift language (4.0) than previous files (unknown ABI version 0x06) file '/Users/xxxxxx/Desktop/Test12/Carthage/Build/iOS/SwiftyJSON.framework/SwiftyJSON' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

#### Environment

List the software versions you're using:

- iOS Version: 12.0
- SwiftyJSON: 4.0
- Xcode Version: 10.0 beta 3 (10L201y)
- Swift Version: 4
- Carthage: 0.30.1

Just wanted to see if anyone has similar issue before raising this issue with SwiftyJSON on Github.

Comment: The error message says that the SwiftyJSON.framework is compiled with older version of Swift, It's 4.0, but Xcode 10 beta comes with 4.2. Try removing all existing builds of carthage and build again.

Comment: I am building the project by selecting Swift version as 4 in Build Settings in Xcode 10.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Swift Language Version in the Build Settings of Xcode 10, is not a Swift compiler version. It's just a flag passed to the compiler telling to run in the compatibility mode of the specified version. Xcode 10 uses Swift 4.2 compiler even if you set 4.0 to the Swift Language Version. And all Swift source codes including linked libraries need to be compiled with the same version of Swift compiler, when you use Xcode 10, it's Swift 4.2.

Comment: My understanding is that I need to get the SwiftyJSON framework compiled with 4.2 from the SwiftyJSON team(GitHub). Please let me know if there is any other way to get that framework on 4.2.

Comment: No, SwiftyJSON is an open source project, you can get whole source code you need and compile it with your own Xcode. Some package managers do such things automatically, though, I'm not good at Carthage that I cannot tell you how.

Comment: oh yeah its totally a dumb understanding.. I totally forgot that I can download and compile that if necessary. Thanks OOper.

To whoever checking this post, I resolved this by doing the below 3 things:
1) Changed the command line tools version to XCode 10
2) Changed the Swift version on Build Settings to 4.2
3) Deleted the carthage folders and ran 'carthage update' once again.

Comment: Better write it as an answer, for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

To whoever checking this post, I resolved this by doing the below 3 things:

1. Changed the command line tools version to Xcode 10
2. Changed the Swift version on Build Settings to 4.2
3. Deleted the carthage folders and ran 'carthage update' once again.